# start_speech_synthesis_task To .mp3 (Amazon Polly)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-polly

I am trying to synthesize ~3600 characters using Amazon Polly via python. Currently I have the following:

```
from boto3 import client as polly_client

polly = polly_client('polly')
response = polly.start_speech_synthesis_task(Engine='neural',
                                            OutputS3KeyPrefix= "InputAudio",
                                            OutputS3BucketName='s3bucketname',
                                            Text= open('script.txt', 'r').read(),
                                            OutputFormat= 'mp3',
                                            VoiceId= 'Amy'
                                            )
```

How do I turn this response into an .mp3 file on my machine? I've been struggling to do this for a while now. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct – `synthesize_speech()` is limited to 3000 billed characters, while `start_speech_synthesis_task()` can do up to 100,000 billable characters.

The `start_speech_synthesis_task()` is **asynchronous** and outputs a file to an Amazon S3 bucket. From the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/polly.html#Polly.Client.start_speech_synthesis_task):

> This operation requires all the standard information needed for speech synthesis, plus the name of an **Amazon S3 bucket for the service to store the output of the synthesis task**... The SpeechSynthesisTask object is available for 72 hours after starting the asynchronous synthesis task.

So, your program would need to:

- Call `start_speech_synthesis_task()`
- Create a loop that checks for the output every few seconds by calling `get_speech_synthesis_task()`
- Downloads the mp3 file from the S3 bucket

See: [Creating Long Audio Files - Amazon Polly](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/asynchronous.html)